# Symfony : Add data from Ajax call to js array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, symfony

I have an Ajax request that fetch data in database.

These data may vary in function of the action that calls the ajax request.

Each time the Ajax request is called, I want some ot these datas to be pushed in a javascript array declared outside of the Ajax function.

The problem is, each time Ajax is called, my function manage to put the wanted data in the array but erases the previous data.

Here is the script :

```
<script>

let myArray = [];

function fetchWeeksForViewportWidth(startDate) {

    //AJAX
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
            url: "{{path('days_json')}}",
            data: {
                //some data
            },
            success: function (data) {

                let trParents = document.getElementsByClassName('project-assignment');
               
                $.each(trParents, function(key, parent) {
                    let assId = parent.dataset.assignmentId;

                    myArray[assId] = [];

                    $.each(data['days'], function(key, value) {
                        
                        myArray[assId][value.code] = 0;
                        
                        //some other treatment
                        
                        if(value.code in data['game']) {
                        
                            myArray[assId][value.code] = data['game'][value.code];
                        
                        });
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                //handle error
                console.log("error")
            }
    });
}

$(document).ready( function () {


    function displayArray(){
        console.log(myArray);

        setTimeout(displayArray, 5000);
    }

    displayArray();

});

</script>
```

Any idea why new data don't add to the ones from previous ajax calls but keep replacing them ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assignment

```
myArray[assId][value.code] = 0;
```

try the push() function of the array

```
myArray[assId].push(0);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: I tried that, and got the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

Comment: sorry, i think You have to try myArray[assId].push(0); ,, as if we go to second index again it is no more array and you can not use the array functions.

Comment: Nope, it pushes the data but :
- I don't anymore have value.code as a key
- I continues to delete previous data

Comment: 3 iterations of the console log (3 ajax call, one that fetches  44 data, one that fetches 32, and one that fetches 44 again) :                                                                              [5_14_1: Array(44), 4_16_1: Array(44), 6_17_1: Array(44)]
                                                                        ******              
[5_14_1: Array(32), 4_16_1: Array(32), 6_17_1: Array(32)]
   ******
[5_14_1: Array(44), 4_16_1: Array(44), 6_17_1: Array(44)]****** I should have 120 entries